# Make movement more smooth

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make this game app.
I basically have this BitMap bMapEgg moving down every time UpdateCourt() gets called in a Surfaceview ChickenView. The problem I'm facing is that it looks really chunky. The movement of the bitmap doesn't look smooth.
`ballPosition.y += 18;` is the code that makes it move.

Any ideas how to make it look smooth?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    static Canvas canvas;
    static ChickenView chickenView;

    //Used for getting display details like the number of pixels
    static Display display;
    static Point size;
    static int screenWidth;
    static int screenHeight;

    static Point ballPosition;
    static int ballWidth;

    static boolean ballIsMovingDown;

    //stats
    static long lastFrameTime;
    static int fps;
    static int score;
    static int lives;

    static float bitmapPositionX ;
    static float bitmapPositionY ;
    static float bitmapWidth ;
    static float bitmapHeight;
    static Bitmap bMapEgg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chickenView = (ChickenView) findViewById(R.id.chickenView);

        //Get the screen size in pixels
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            display.getSize(size);
        }
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

        ballWidth = screenWidth / 35;
        ballPosition = new Point();
        ballPosition.x = screenWidth / 2;
        ballPosition.y = 1 + ballWidth;

        final ImageView imageEggs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageEggs);
        final ImageView imageUpgrade = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageUpgrade);
        TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEggs);
        imageUpgrade.setOnTouchListener(this);
        chickenView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageUpgrade:
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    final int x = (int) event.getX();
                    final int y = (int) event.getY();

                    //now map the coords we got to the
                    //bitmap (because of scaling)
                    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
                    Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

                    //now check alpha for transparency
                    int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
                    if (alpha != 0) {
                        //do whatever you would have done for your click event here
                        Intent i;
                        i = new Intent(this, StructureActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case R.id.chickenView:
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                // Replace these with the correct values (bitmap x, y, width & height)
                float x1 = bitmapPositionX;
                float x2 = x1 + bitmapWidth;
                float y1 = bitmapPositionY;
                float y2 = y1 + bitmapHeight;
                // Test to see if touch is inside the bitmap
                if (x > x1 && x < x2 && y > y1 && y < y2) {
                    // Bitmap was touched
                    Log.v("test", "test");
                } else {
                    Log.v("werkt ghil ni", "test");
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    static class ChickenView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread ourThread = null;
        SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        volatile boolean playingSquash;
        Paint paint;

        public ChickenView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
        }

        public ChickenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }

        public ChickenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        private void init(Context context) {
            ourHolder = getHolder();
            paint = new Paint();
            ballIsMovingDown = true;
        }



        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (playingSquash) {
                updateCourt();
                drawCourt();
                controlFPS();
            }

        }


        public void updateCourt() {


            //depending upon the two directions we should be
            //moving in adjust our x any positions
            if (ballIsMovingDown) {
                ballPosition.y += 18;
            }

            //if hits bottom
            if (ballPosition.y > screenHeight - 7*ballWidth) {
                ballIsMovingDown = false;


            }

        }

        public void drawCourt()  {

            if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                //Paint paint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//the background
                paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                paint.setTextSize(45);
                canvas.drawText("Score:" + score + " Lives:" + lives + " fps:" + fps, 20, 40, paint);

                Bitmap bMapEgg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.egg);
                bMapEgg = scaleDown(bMapEgg,180, true);

                Bitmap bMapBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backgrounddd);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bMapBackground, 0, 0, paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bMapEgg, ballPosition.x, ballPosition.y, paint);

                bitmapPositionX = ballPosition.x;
                bitmapPositionY = ballPosition.y;

                bitmapWidth = bMapEgg.getWidth();
                bitmapHeight = bMapEgg.getHeight();

                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

        }

        public void controlFPS() {
            long timeThisFrame = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFrameTime);
            long timeToSleep = 15 - timeThisFrame;
            if (timeThisFrame > 0) {
                fps = (int) (1000 / timeThisFrame);
            }
            if (timeToSleep > 0) {

                try {
                    ourThread.sleep(timeToSleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }

            lastFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }


        public void pause() {
            playingSquash = false;
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }

        public void resume() {
            playingSquash = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        while (true) {
            chickenView.pause();
            break;
        }

        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        chickenView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        chickenView.pause();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            chickenView.pause();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize,
                                   boolean filter) {
        float ratio = Math.min(
                (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
                (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
        int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
        int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width,
                height, filter);
        return newBitmap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in each frame you decode and scale all bitmaps all over again.

Move your bitmaps decoding and scaling out of the draw method, put it in an initialization method and store decoded and scaled bitmaps in member variables (maybe even static ones) so you can just reuse them for drawing in each frame.